# Get the Text of a specific Textbox (not all) inside a Panel control

Tags: vb.net

How can I get the text from a Textbox and only this Textbox inside a Panel control in a visual studio Form. Panel is Panel1 and Textbox is txtbox. Thank you.

Comment: Umm, `txtbox.Text`?

Comment: texbox is child of Panel1 so does not work that easy as you post Ahmed Abdelhameed

Comment: Yes, it does. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50430647/edit) your question, show your code, and explain what your expectations are and what the code does instead along with any error messages you might have. Right now it's unclear what your problem is.

Comment: txtbox is inside Panel1, so is a child of Panle1. I am no expert in this topic. I understand that first I have to loop the parent and find the child in this case the txtbox control and than get the text form the textbox. Get it ?

Comment: I've answered this question elsewhere and you said there that the control was added at design-time, so it absolutely DOES work exactly as @AhmedAbdelhameed suggests. The only reason that it wouldn't is if the control was added at run-time, but you specifically told me that that was not the case. Regardless, this question is inadequate. ALWAYS provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. Provide the relevant code, show us what you have tried and explain what happened when you tried it. If the suggestion didn;t work then something unexpected happened. EXPLAIN THAT!

Comment: "I understand that first I have to loop the parent and find the child".  No, you do not. You only need to do that for controls added at run-time.  As I've explained elsewhere, each control added at design-time has a dedicated field, i.e. member variable, that refers to it directly so its parent is irrelevant. You've already been told what to do so why are we still discussing it? If you had actually done as instructed then you'd already know it worked. If it didn't work then you should have explained exactly what happened when you tried it. That would also mean you gave me false information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use txtbox.text to get text.

Comment: Searching I found some examples. Let me show you one ok ?.

Comment: Is not my case but as you can see it is an example of how to locate controls in the Controls collection. As I mention before , I am no expert to write a similar code for the textbox.

Comment: Do you have added the textbox at runtime.

Comment: If no then please post your code for review.